# Null value for Put Request in RestApi

Tags: rest, api, .net-core, http-put

I'm coding Rest API with .NET Core. I am having a problem. I use Postman for test.
For example; My variable: name, surname, age.

```
(Normally: ID:1, name: Amet, surname: Asar, age:30)
```

I'm using Put request.

```
{
  "ID": 1
  "name": "Ayhan",
  "surname":"Hara"
}
```

But I don't send "age". So, it's saving null value for age.

Like;

```
id=1, name=Ayhan, surname=Hara, age=null
```

How can check null variable? If the age value has not enter, don't change.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody]JsonPutDocument<Customer_UserDTO> customer_UserDTO)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("İstenilen Datalar Düzgün Değil");

    var user = unitOfWork.customer_User.GetById(id);
    if (user == null)
        return NotFound("İlgili müşteri bulunamadı");

    var userToPut = mapper.Map<Customer_UserDTO>(user);
    customer_UserDTO.ApplyTo(userToPut, ModelState);
    mapper.Map(userToPut, user);
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(mapper.Map<Customer_User>(user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [Patch]. Specifically, this blog will help you: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/

Your only other real alternative is to manually map the properties based on your own conditions.

Alternatively, it might be a question for the Automapper guys at: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Actually no, usage questions are better asked on SO.